# Sharepoint Application Creates .ICS file in plaint text how to force HTML

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, office365, icalendar, sharepoint-apps

We are running a SharePoint application that can populate a business process in an outlook agenda by using the .ICS file. When opening the .ICS file the outlook meeting invite is generated as a plain text file, therefore hyperlinks do not work. Can you force the ICS file to be an HTML file?

The .ICS file looks like the following:

```
> BEGIN:VCALENDAR PRODID:Microsoft CDO for Microsoft Exchange
> VERSION:2.0
> 
> BEGIN:VEVENT UID:20201028T080132Z@a.com SEQUENCE:0
> DTSTAMP:20201028T080132Z CREATED:20201028T080132Z
> LAST-MODIFIED:20201028T090132Z X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
> DTSTART:20201218T000000Z DTEND: SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Test
> Meeting ATTENDEE;CN="Doe, John [Business]";RSVP=TRUE:a@a.com
> ATTENDEE;CN="Doe, John [Business]";RSVP=TRUE:a@a.com
```

Comment: can you have a look this? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook/outlook-2016-ics-description-shows-no-html/08d06cba-bfe4-4757-a052-adab64ea75a2

Comment: Koen, I don't believe you can.  A .ics file has a specification (RFC5545) which defines it as text and calendar applications generally do not expect html in the description field and some will not treat it as html.  Some try make links clickable.   You could use the ALTREP https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.2.1.